# Sqlite3 searching through user selected database

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

```
import sqlite3

students = 5
prac = "Food Tests"

db = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = db.cursor()
c.execute('''SELECT equipment FROM ... ''')
equipment = c.fetchall()
```

Is there any possible way to search through a user selected database in sqlite3? In this case the database would be chosen from the prac variable which is selected by the user earlier in the program by a tkinter OptionMenu. So the SQL statement would be SELECT equipment FROM [Food Tests].

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use parameter substitution for table names. You have to construct this part of the query yourself. But you *should* use parameter substitution for everything else:

```
student_id = 5
query = "SELECT equipment FROM {tbl!r} WHERE student = ?".format(tbl=prac)
c.execute(query, student_id)
```

By using `tbl!r` instead of just `tbl` we insert quoted table name, in case it contains whitespace characters.

Comment: Python and SQL use different quoting rules.